# Google Colab causes high memory usage in local?

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, tqdm

I'm now running a model training on Google Colab. It was just a minute ago, the local system message popped out and said that the memory is about to exhaust (meanwhile I didn't run anything).

Now my memory usage is 40%, but everytime I open up Colab, the local memory usage peak to 80 and keeps increasing. The Colab page freeze so I couldn't stop the current runtime.

How is that possible? Shouldn't Colab be an online environment? Can it be related to the `tqdm` package? Because previous version ran well, this situation only happens when I just add `tqdm` to show progress bars on the screen.

Comment: Similar symptoms, was using PyTorch with PyTorch Lightning. For me, it seems that every validation step results in a new tqdm bar in the notebook, among other issues. I bypassed the problem like Rey with the compressor, by reducing (actually increasing) progress_bar_refresh_rate to 50 and setting full validation to maybe once every 50 epochs with check_val_every_n_epoch.  Still no idea what the root cause is though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you connected your Colab instance to a local Jupyter instance ever? Colab should default to using hosted environment resources over local ones. The tqdm package is preinstalled for python in Colab, and works fine in my notebooks. Can you share a minimum reproducible example?

First, I would try looking at the memory from the notebook by running

```
!cat /proc/meminfo
```

Colab instances should have between 12-30 Gb of total memory. If its tracking local memory, you should be able to tell.

Next, I would try saving your code, closing Colab, then reopening it. Be sure when you reconnect, select "connect to hosted runtime" in the connection dropdown menu (upper right corner, below the GDrive menu bar).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't solve this. But I switched to `progressbar` after Colab stopped my session automatically. And this situation did not happen again. I will try tracking memory if something similar comes up again.

Comment: Good luck! If you do find a solution/have the problem again, please post your solution here. Though I haven't run into this problem yet, others have, and it would be great to find a solution.

Comment: Having the same problem, even with restart - did you ever figure it out? It seems like come computation is happening locally, even with remote runtime selected